# Notice: Array to String Converstion in Doctrain Query

Tags: php, arrays, string, symfony, doctrine-orm

> Notice: Array to String Conversion in Doctrine Query

```
foreach($listLocations as $k=>$location){
    $list[] = "'".$location['id']."'";
}
```

`$storesList = implode(',', $list);` // Prints string(23)"'191','195','215','265'"

```
$storesList = (string)$storesList;
```

i changed it to String but in Query it Still considering as Array

```
$sql="SELECT * from tbl_students WHERE s.store_id IN (".$storesList .")";
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();     
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) First of all change:

```
$list[] = "'".$location['id']."'";
```

To

```
$list[] = $location['id'];
```

b) Now do like below:-

```
$storesList = "('".implode("','", $list)."')";
```

c) And

```
$sql="SELECT * from tbl_students WHERE s.store_id IN $storesList";
```

Example link for help:-https://eval.in/736486

Comment: nice and quick answer. well example.

Comment: Thanks for answer, But Still i am Encountering the Same issue.

Comment: Thanks its Because of Some other issue, i Fixed it Thanks for Help.

Comment: @Developer  glad to help you :):)